# Can I safely attach new fittings to an older PEX A line?

Tags: plumbing, pex, cutting, fitting

I have a 10yr old "PEX A" line (red, 1/2", "potable," "100PSI") running to my rear hose bib.  I'd like to install a tee in this existing line and run a branch to the side of the house.  I am hesitant to use the PEX cutting tool on this line due to its age.  I am also concerned the pipe, which seems smaller in diameter than the new material, will split rather than expand with the expander tool.  Does anyone have any suggestions/recommendations when attaching new fittings to older PEX A?

Answer (score 2):

> I am hesitant to use the PEX cutting tool on this line due to its age.

Umm, 10 years is nothing for PEX. If its age truly concerned you then shouldn't you be more worried about keeping it in service where it risks flooding your house?

Like the other answer states, there should be no issue with cutting and adding a tee to the existing line unless it's had prolonged UV exposure.

If you're truly worried about using the expansion tool on your line then you can try a [push-to-connect fitting such as SharkBite brand.](https://www.sharkbite.com/products/brass-push-tee-0)

I have several push-to-connect fittings in use in my home and they haven't leaked a single time since they were installed 2 years ago; albeit  I only installed them in easily accessible basement joints. Just make sure to push the PEX line to the proper depth.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate your response.

Comment: You're welcome. Did you ever end up making a decision?

Answer (score 1):

PEX is stable it does not dry rot so it should not split unless it has been subjected to sunlight or uv radiation.